# Code Coverage Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, code-coverage

I want to enable code coverage for some unit test in my solution. After adding the test

project and double clicking the Local.testsettings file, I couldn't see the "data and

Diagnostics" and "Roles" option in the window.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 professional edition.

Could someone provide me a thread on how to configure code coverage and how to see the above options in my vs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code Coverage is only available in Visual Studio Premium and Ultimate.

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison